# PDF is not accessible through URL in IIS .NET Framework 4.8 app

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, iis, internal-server-error

I have a PDF file in a folder on a server within a IIS website app that I need to be able to open through a link/url, like below:

https://api.example.com/my-path/my-pdf-file.pdf

The PDF file is hosted in a folder of my IIS application. When I try to access it through the link, I've got a 500 server error.

I tried several things within IIS settings (URL Rules, web.config, mime-types), but nothing worked so far.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You might see what else FRT can tell you about the error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis and get started from there.

Comment: Try to check the IIS logs and check the sub-status code for those requests. Check that the PDF file opens fine directly in the browser. Try to replace the problematic PDF with any other PDF, and see if it works. Try to place any other type of file(e.g. PNG) and try to access it. See if it shows the same error. Does your site work fine? except for this PDF issue. Generally, it shows 500 errors when there is some issue with the application. Try to check the MIME type is added for PDF in the IIS.

Comment: Yes - the app works perfectly. I have an .NET WEB API 2 project as the website. I just want to be able read from the "web" the pdf file(s). Mime Type is added for the IIS and the WEB API website as well

Comment: Could you please inform us what result you got with the other file types? Are those files are accessible? Does the issue only occur with the PDF files? As suggested by Lex Li, please check the FRT logs. See whether it is any permission issue for the files or folder.

Comment: It happens the same with .png or .jpg etc. I can see 500 Error in the IIS logs and those files are accessible within the server and have rights permissions. I solved the issues by retrieving the PDF file(s) to the UI through a blob file, using Memory Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder included in the project? You can't just add a folder outside of Visual Studio, but have to use VS to add that folder.

You can right click on that existing folder (which of course is a sub folder of your project) and check this setting:

So, in my case, I right click on UpLoadFiles.

If the folder ALREADY is included in the project, then you get a option to EXCLUDE the folder like this:

[image]

However, if the folder is not included, then you see this:

[image]

so, is that folder included in your project? You want to check above.

Comment: Hi Albert! Thanks for the tip. It still doesn't work. Indeed, the folder was not included, so I included in the csproj, then deploy the solution, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ok, so the folder is fixed, now check the pdf in the folder - is it included in the project?

Comment: Hmm, that's something that might not work as from the app I am generating these PDF files and store them in that folder. I can have 1 to many PDF files in the folder...

Comment: Then that should work fine.